# The size of mdf file is much bigger than its gdb file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, file-geodatabase

The size of mdf file is much bigger than its gdb file.

As all the content of mdf file is exported (or imported) to a gdb, the size drops dramatically. The size of mdf is 8GB while its corresponding gdb is 200MB!!!

[image]

[image]

How can I “clean” the mdf file so that it gets as small as the gdb?

Comment: Different file formats use different storage protocols. I doubt there is a way for a SQL Server  relational database to be as small as file geodatabase.

Comment: Did you run a Compress on your SQL database from ArcCatalog?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to shrink the SQL file? [This page](http://www.sqlserverlogexplorer.com/how-to-shrink-mdf-file/) tells you how.

In brief:

- Connect to the SQL Server Management Studio, Go to Databases
- Select the desired database that needs to be shrunk
- Right-click on the database, Select Tasks >> Shrink >> Files

Though - as pointed out- different formats store data in different ways and there is no guarantee that the same features in two different formats will produce files of the same size.

Comment: Yes, but this option has bad impact on the indexes of the database and may lead to slower performance. which is not accepted!

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I'd be surprised that they had an option that would purposely slow things down. But even if it does, I don't see many other options.

Comment: Midavalo, I tried it with no effect, and I couldn't find a massive solution until now!!